# how to fetch all rows from mysql using mysqli_fetch_assoc and convert to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have tried to get all the rows from mysql table for that am using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. While using this am getting only one row. I need to convert the resulting array into JSON.

```
$query  =   "SELECT * FROM db_category WHERE publish='1'";
$result =   mysqli_query($c, $query) or die(mysqli_error($c));
$length =   mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($length > 0)
{       
    $var['status']  =   'success';

    while($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $var = array_merge($var, $obj);
        $var1 = json_encode($var);
    }
    echo '{"slider":['.$var1.']}';
}
else
{
    $arr    =   array('status'=>"notfound");
    echo '{"slider":['.json_encode($arr).']}';
}
```

Now the output for above code is,

```
{"slider":[{"status":"success","category_id":"12","category_name":"Books","publish":"1"}]}
```

Required output is,

`{"slider":[{"status":"success","category_id":"1","category_name":"Apparel","publish":"1"},{"status":"success","category_id":"2","category_name":"Footwear","publish":"1"},{"status":"success","category_id":"3","category_name":"Furniture","publish":"1"},{"status":"success","category_id":"4","category_name":"Jewellery","publish":"1"}]}`

How to solve this issue.

Comment: you should not hand code json. put everything into array and at the end call the json_encode.

Comment: @bansi : same result. Only one row is getting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it simply by [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. And you can also get all data into array, with [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function :

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$jsonData = json_encode(array('slider'=>$data, 'status' => 'success'));
```

If you want to put `'status'=>'success'` for each row, do it like this (before `json_encode`)

```
foreach($data as $key => $dataRow) {
   $data[$key]['status'] = 'success';
}
```

Comment: now the result is `{"slider":[{"status":"success","0":{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Apparel","publish":"1"},"1":{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Footwear","publish":"1"},"2":{"category_id":"3","category_name":"Furniture","publish":"1"},"3":{"category_id":"4","category_name":"Jewellery","publish":"1"}}]}`

Comment: @TareqMahmood : am also using `array_merge`

Comment: You don't need to, just add the `status` into the array which we are doing `json_encode`. See my latest edit.

Comment: also for the else you can use `echo json_encode(array('slider'=>array('status'=>'notfound')));`

Comment: @JithinVarghese [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) merges the array not adds

Comment: @TareqMahmood : your code is working. Now the result is `{"slider":[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Apparel","publish":"1"},{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Footwear","publish":"1"},{"category_id":"3","category_name":"Furniture","publish":"1"},{"category_id":"4","category_name":"Jewellery","publish":"1"}],"status":"success"}`. I want the result as `{"slider":[{"status":"success","category_id":"1","category_name":"Apparel","publish":"1"},{"status":"success","category_id":"2","category_name":"Footwear","publish":"1"}`

Comment: @JithinVarghese, You can accept the answer, if that works.

Comment: @TareqMahmood : see my above comment. It's not working. Not working as i expected. See my required output.

Comment: @JithinVarghese, sorry, but you wrote, "working" above, instead of "not working".

Comment: @TareqMahmood : sorry about that. It was my mistake.

Comment: @JithinVarghese, np. so you want 'status' => 'success', to be put into each of the row?